# Как вывести список постов, в которых нет отметок "Мне нравится" от пользователя?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Привет, есть у меня ссылки на посты в VK (их более 1 000 штук). Мой ID ВКонтакте, например, 52, и в 790 постах есть мои отметки **Мне нравится**.

Как вывести все те посты, в которых **нет моих отметок Мне нравится**?

Знаю, что используется API метод `likes.getList`. Но получается, что мне нужно всё проверять этим методом в цикле? Есть ли другой способ сделать такую проверку?

Comment: Ну что, мой ответ помог, нет?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да помог, спасибо Вам огромное. Напрактике я канешно его еще не пременял потомучто времени пока нет, но назаметку себе взял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант использовать фильтр, который просто просеет данные, исходя из первого ответа. Напишу примерно на `php`

Допустим, мы получили массив через метод `execute` (можно и обычным методом, не суть)

```
var posts = API.wall.get({owner_id: 666});
return posts.items;
```

Результат (обозначим его переменно **$response**, к примеру ) будет содержать в себе массив с информацией по каждому посту. У каждого поста есть поле `likes`, которое, в свою очередь, содержит поле `user_likes`, которое как раз отвечает за то, поставил сам юзер лайк или нет. Если оно равно `0`, значит не поставил, если `1`, значит поставил. Соответственно надо нарисовать функцию фильтрации

```
function filterPosts($el) {
    // юзер не ставил лайк
    return($el['likes']['user_likes'] == 0);
}
```

и вызываем функцию фильтрации:

```
$response = array_filter($response , "filterPosts");
sort($response);
```

**array_filter** - Фильтрует элементы массива с помощью callback-функции. Обходит каждое значение массива `array`, передавая его в callback-функцию. Если callback-функция возвращает `true`, данное значение из `array` возвращается в результирующий массив. Ключи массива сохраняются.

**sort** - отсортировать ключи.

DONE!